# Small set in partition-large class

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability

A collection   $\mathcal{A}\subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$
is $k$-*large* in $X$
if for every $k$-partition
 of $X$ namely
$X_1,\cdots,X_k$, there exists an $i\leq k$ such that $X_i\in \mathcal{A}$;
$\mathcal{A}$ is *upward closed* if for every $X\subseteq Y$,
$X\in \mathcal{A}$ implies $Y\in \mathcal{A}$.

Fix a $0<\delta<1/2$, $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Let $N$ be very large, $\mathcal{A}\subseteq\mathcal{P}(\{1,\cdots,N\})$ is $k$-large in $\{1,\cdots,N\}$ and upward closed. Let $Z$ be a uniformly random $N/k$-element  subset of $\{1,\cdots,N\}$.

> Question: Is it true that there exists a $\delta N$-element subset $Z'$ of $\{1,\cdots,N\}$ such that with high probability (as $N\rightarrow\infty$): $Z\cup Z'\in\mathcal{A}$.

[Katona, Gyula (1975) The Hamming-sphere has minimum boundary. STUDIA SCIENTIARUM MATHEMATICARUM HUNGARICA, 10. pp. 131-140. ISSN 0081-6906](http://real.mtak.hu/21110/)

Theorem 3 of [KG1975] gives the following:
for every $\mathcal{A}'\subseteq 2^N$ with $|\mathcal{A}'|/2^N=c>0$,
let $\rho\in 2^N$ be uniformly random, then $d_H(\rho,\mathcal{A}) = O_p(\sqrt{N})$. Where $d_H$ denote the Hamming distance. This implies a weaker "answer"  of above question:
with high probability, there exists a $Z'$ (depending on $Z$)
such that $Z\cup Z'\in \mathcal{A}\wedge |Z'|<\delta N$.

I wonder if the following (which implies a positive answer to above question) holds:

> For every $\mathcal{A}'\subseteq 2^N$ with $|\mathcal{A}'|/2^N\geq c>0$, every $\delta>0$,
>   there exists a set $Z'\subseteq N$ with $|Z'|<\delta N$ such that let 
>   $\rho\in 2^N$ be uniformly random, then with hight probability:
>   there exists a $\sigma\in \mathcal{A}'$ such that $\rho$ agree with $\sigma$ on 
>   $N\setminus Z'$.

Comment: I don't know the answer in general, but it's true if $\mathcal A$ consists of all sets of measure at least $1/k$, for some measure $\mu$ on $[N]$...